# Redux how dispatch multiple action types with fetch method

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I'm trying to make api call with fetch method from Redux, i create some action types like fetch_start, fetch_success and fetch_failed.

but i cant my reducer nothing return to me. When i check redux dev tool there is 3 action types too working. Where i mistake?

i'm using thunk, redux

here is my component:

```
class SignInComponent extends Component {

    signIn = () => {
        this.props.signIn()
    }

    render() {

    return (
      <Row className="justify-content-md-center">
         <Col lg={4}>
              <button type="button" onClick={this.signIn}>
              </button>
              </Col>
      </Row>
    )
  }
}


  const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    users: state.users
  })

  function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
      signIn: bindActionCreators(signIn, dispatch)
    }
  } 

  export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SignInComponent)
```

here is my reducer:

```
import { SIGNIN_START, SIGNIN_SUCCESS, SIGNIN_FAILED } from '../../actions/Auth/SignIn'

let initialState = []

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case SIGNIN_START:
            return console.log('start')
        case SIGNIN_SUCCESS:
            return console.log("success")  
        case SIGNIN_FAILED:
            return console.log("fail")        
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

here is my action:

```
export const SIGNIN_START = 'SIGNIN_START';
export const SIGNIN_SUCCESS = 'SIGNIN_SUCCESS';
export const SIGNIN_FAILED = 'SIGNIN_FAILED';

export const signIn = () => {
    return(dispatch) => {
        dispatch({
            type: SIGNIN_START
        })
        fetch('https://api.com/signIn')
        .then((response) => {
            dispatch({
                type: SIGNIN_SUCCESS
            })
        })
        .catch((err) => {
        dispatch({
            type: SIGNIN_FAILED
        })
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: you are dispatching object instead of function you have to dispatch the function

Comment: Your code is all correct, but you aren't returning your state from your reducer, you're just returning a console.log. It needs to at least return the initial state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to return the new state in the reducer for each action

```
return console.log();
```

will simply returns `undefined`.

change it to

```
switch (action.type) {
  case SIGNIN_START:
     console.log('start')
     return [...state];
  case SIGNIN_SUCCESS:
     console.log("success")
     return [...state];
  case SIGNIN_FAILED:
     console.log("fail");
     return [...state];    
  default:
     return state
 }
```

Comment: I understood everything work well thank you so much :)